# How to add a secret using a post-initialization script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need a secret text to be configured in a [post-initialization script](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script) in my Jenkins. Until now I only found [code to configure username/password credentials](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217708168-create-credentials-from-groovy), but I just don't know the right classes to use for a secret text. My current approach is:

```groovy
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.*;
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*;
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.*;

Credentials c = (Credentials) new WhateverClassSecretText(
    CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
    "my-credential-id",
    "Secret Text for something", 
    "S3cr3t") // TODO find right class here!

SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().addCredentials(Domain.global(), c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it but I'm still curious if anyone has a better solution.

The class I was looking for is [`org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/plain-credentials/org/jenkinsci/plugins/plaincredentials/impl/StringCredentialsImpl.html), which actually takes a [`hudson.util.Secret`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/util/Secret.html) as the secret string. Here is the code (testable in Jenkins Script Console):

```groovy
import static com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsScope.GLOBAL

import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider
import hudson.util.Secret
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl

StringCredentialsImpl credentials = new StringCredentialsImpl(
    GLOBAL,
    "my-credential-id",
    "Secret Text for something",
    Secret.fromString("S3cr3t"))

SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().addCredentials(Domain.global(), credentials)
```